# IPhone programming move line circle etc

Tags: iphone, ios

In my iPhone application i want do draw different shapes like line, circle and what i want that i want to move those shapes one by one on finger touch. I can draw different shapes but dont know how to move that shape like line and circle.

I have used uiimageview to draw. Please help .

Comment: Before anyone can answer, you need to supply more information. How are you modelling your shapes, how are you drawing them, and what have your tried so far as to getting them to move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `UIView` for drawing a shape, implement `drawRect` to draw the shape in it, and implement the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` to move the same, now each time you want to add a new drawing to your `main view`, create a new instance of your `DrawingUIView` and add it to the main view

Each drawing will have its `DrawingUIView`, moving these shapes will be done as you would normally move any `UIView` using the touches events

Answer (score 0):

It can be quite difficult to know what shape you should be moving.

I suggest that you read through Ole Begemann's [blog post on CGPath Hit Testing](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/). It explains how you can determine what shape should be dragged and also includes a sample project on GitHub.